# WP Query for Posts (Products) in Specific Category that has 2 Specific Tags (*AND* both tags not *OR*)

Tags: wp-query, terms, tags, tax-query

This is really confusing me.

I've tried numerous things but cannot get appropriate results.

Here's what I currently have for my query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'ring' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'black', 'men' ),
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

As you can see I am trying to return products in the product category `ring` that contain both the tags `black` AND `men`...

It appears though the `product_tag` `terms` array which includes `black` and `men`, is returning posts that include the tag `black` OR the tag `men` in the `ring` category.

How do I get it so that only products that include BOTH the tags in the query are returned?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I (think) I got it...

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'ring' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'black', 'men' ),
            'operator' => 'AND'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Missing the `'operator'` => `'AND'` key value pair