# Get single post from tags array

Tags: loop

I have wordpress and many posts. Every post have on tag. Posts may have same tags.

I have:

```
post1 tag1 date1
post2 tag1 date2
post3 tag2 date3
post4 tag3 date4
post5 tag2 date5
```

I have get:

```
post1
post3
post4
```

That is, I want to select from all posts one post from posts with the same tag and the earliest by date of publication.

I assume the following algorithm:

1. Get all tags of blog
2. Get posts for each tag
3. Get last date post for each tag
4. Show all posts from step 3.

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to achieve but I just got done doing something somewhat similar, I think your answer is probably along the same lines.  [WP Query for Posts (Products) in Specific Category that has 2 Specific Tags (*AND* both tags not *OR*)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/365887/wp-query-for-posts-products-in-specific-category-that-has-2-specific-tags-an)

Comment: What helped me was looking at the different options in the `WP Query` Documentation here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/ ... you can filter and get whatever posts you want using this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$args = array(
        'type' => 'post',
        'orderby' => 'name'
);
$tags = get_tags($args);
foreach($tags as $tag) { 
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'tag='.$tag->name );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $desired_posts[] = get_the_ID(); // all the post IDs stored here.
    } else {
    // no posts found
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
$args1 = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'post__in' => $desired_posts,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
); 
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args1 );
    echo '<ul>';
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
      echo '<li>'. get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }
    } else {
    // no posts found
    }
    echo '</ul>';`

Comment: Thanx for you comment. 
Can I after this code sort this posts by date?

Comment: @antohabio The code is sorted by date i.e. the latest post will be displayed first which is a default value for the query.

Comment: Please see https://cherepovets.org/. First list - is you code. Post sorting by tag name alphabeticaly, not by date.
You code: 1 - get tags, 2 - get post by this tags and end. Can I next sort this posts by date?

Comment: @antohabio Please try this code.

Comment: Whatever sort by tag date modified, not by posts date modified(

Comment: @antohabio I have modified the code and sorted the posts by date now. Please check.

Comment: Wonderfull! This work. But pagination with this don't work now.

Comment: @antohabio I have specified to display all product here "'posts_per_page' => -1" you can edit this to add as many products you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107702/discussion-between-antohabio-and-made2popular).